# iOS - Do GIFs in rich push notifications play

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

If a GIF is sent in a rich push notification, does it play in the notification itself or would the notification have to be tapped first?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer: No**, we don't have to tap the notification first.

As of iOS 10, Apple gave developers the ability to produce Rich Notifications. These are capable of displaying attachments (thumbnails), or displaying media such as images, animated GIFs and videos. The notification payload should have mutable content key set:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "body": "Some data here",
            "title": "title"
        },
        "mutable-content": 1
    },
    "attachment-url": "https://someURl"
}
```

Because of the mutable-content key, the notification is not shown directly to the user. Instead, we’ve got 30 seconds to execute some code, download resources and edit the notification.

Read this medium post for source code and further explanation:
[Rich Notifications](https://www.avanderlee.com/ios-10/rich-notifications-ios-10/)

Comment: Your links seem to be broken.

Comment: Updated the link. Should be fine now.